# Pinescript TRADINGVIIEW - Why isn't this working? Trying to highlight if the most recent candle has a larger body than the previous 30 candles

Tags: pine-script

```
study("Candle CHoCH" , shorttitle="Big CHoCH", overlay = true)


BullColor=#E1BF16
BearColor=#E15C75

BodyRange()=>
    math.abs(close - open)

highestBodyRange = ta.highest(BodyRange(), 30)[1]

BigBear = (open-close) > highestBodyRange
plotshape(BigBear , style = shape.arrowup , location = location.belowbar , text = "Bear", color = BearColor)
barcolor(BigBear ? BearColor : na)

BigBull = (close-open) > highestBodyRange
plotshape(BigBull , style = shape.arrowup , location = location.abovebar , text = "Bull", color = BullColor)
barcolor(BigBull ? BullColor : na)

alertcondition(BigBull, "Long Alert",  "Go long")
alertcondition(BigBear, "Short Alert", "Go short ")
```

The Error is:
Could not find function or function reference math.abs

I just want it to color in the most recent candle if it has a larger body than the previous 30 candles. It's not working. Is it something to do with not being able to have your own functions, in this case BodyRange(), in a study? Or have I made an error in the code and if so what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like to combined a few things but forgot to reference the version number of pine to use  + used "study" rather "indicator". You can read more about it [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/writing/Style_guide.html#version).

Try the below.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Your Indicator", overlay=true)


BullColor=#E1BF16
BearColor=#E15C75

BodyRange()=>
    math.abs(close - open)

highestBodyRange = ta.highest(BodyRange(), 30)[1]

BigBear = (open-close) > highestBodyRange
plotshape(BigBear , style = shape.arrowup , location = location.belowbar , text = "Bear", color = BearColor)
barcolor(BigBear ? BearColor : na)

BigBull = (close-open) > highestBodyRange
plotshape(BigBull , style = shape.arrowup , location = location.abovebar , text = "Bull", color = BullColor)
barcolor(BigBull ? BullColor : na)

alertcondition(BigBull, "Long Alert",  "Go long")
alertcondition(BigBear, "Short Alert", "Go short ")
```